# CASE statement based on SUM results in query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a query where I am using SUM to total up bill detail values. I would like to create a `CASE` statement that works off the results of that sum, rather than the values being summed. Below is a partial example of what my query currently looks like.

```
SELECT 
    bill.billnumber_id, 
    billdetail.billclass, 
    SUM(billdetail.amount) AS Amount
GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
```

Say this totals 4 lines of `billdetail` (2, 0, 5, 3) for a summed amount of 10. I would like to do a `CASE` statement based on the 10 amount, rather than the individual values. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to _do_ with the `CASE` statement?

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help. I tried to the top two replies and they both worked. Thanks even to Laf for making my post look better. I'm still trying to figure out how to properly post my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, SUM(billdetail.amount) AS Amount,
       (case when SUM(billdetail.amount) > 10 then 'BigOne'
             else 'Little'
        end)
GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Amount = 0 THEN 'Nothing' ELSE 'somthing' END AmountComment
FROM(
  SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, SUM(billdetail.amount) AS Amount
  GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
)x
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either make it a subquery:

```
SELECT billnumber_id, billclass, CASE WHEN Amount = 10 THEN ... ELSE ... END
FROM
(
  SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, SUM(billdetail.amount) AS Amount
  GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
) A
```

Or just repeat the aggregation:

```
SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, SUM(billdetail.amount) AS Amount
     , CASE WHEN SUM(billdetail.amount) = 10 THEN ... ELSE ... END
GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, (Select SUM(billdetail.amount) from billdetail)
AS Amount
from bill inner join billdetail on bill.id = buildetail.kBillId 
/* include from join (not added above)*/
GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
```

I believe this is what you are after... you might wanat to include the same `from` structure in your inner select statement as:

```
 SELECT bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass, (Select SUM(billdetail.amount) from bill inner
join billdetail on bill.id = buildetail.kBillId ) AS Amount
from bill inner join billdetail on bill.id = buildetail.kBillId 
/* include from join (not added above)*/
GROUP BY bill.billnumber_id, billdetail.billclass
```

Let me know if this is what you meant.